# How to make svg-arrows of the same length?

Tags: html, css, svg

How do I make the right arrow the same length as the left arrow? This is a section called .services and this is a slider for the whole page and to go to the desired section you need to click "Узнать подробнее"

Site http://ca50234.tmweb.ru/

Code [jsfiddle.net/oaxusr8h/](http://jsfiddle.net/oaxusr8h/)

[image]

[image]

```css
.arrows-block {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrows-block">

    <!-- Arrow left -->
    <div class="swiper-button-prev-custom">
        <svg width="81" height="8" viewBox="0 0 81 8" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M0.646446 3.64644C0.451187 3.8417 0.451187 4.15828 0.646446 4.35355L3.82843 7.53553C4.02369 7.73079 4.34027 7.73079 4.53554 7.53553C4.7308 7.34027 4.7308 7.02368 4.53554 6.82842L1.70711 3.99999L4.53554 1.17157C4.7308 0.976304 4.7308 0.659722 4.53554 0.464459C4.34027 0.269197 4.02369 0.269197 3.82843 0.464459L0.646446 3.64644ZM81 3.5L1 3.49999L1 4.49999L81 4.5L81 3.5Z" fill="white" />
        </svg>
    </div>

    <!-- Arrow right -->
    <div class="swiper-button-next-custom">
        <svg width="81" height="8" viewBox="0 0 81 8" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M55.3536 4.35355C55.5488 4.15829 55.5488 3.84171 55.3536 3.64645L52.1716 0.464466C51.9763 0.269204 51.6597 0.269204 51.4645 0.464466C51.2692 0.659728 51.2692 0.976311 51.4645 1.17157L54.2929 4L51.4645 6.82843C51.2692 7.02369 51.2692 7.34027 51.4645 7.53553C51.6597 7.7308 51.9763 7.7308 52.1716 7.53553L55.3536 4.35355ZM0 4.5H55V3.5H0V4.5Z" fill="white" />
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are no arrows both on JSFiddle and your demo site. Also, every click on the left menu "Наши услуги" causes an error `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'div.services-info>div.content>div.' is not a valid selector.`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the right arrow SVG and rotate it to be the left arrow. Also, your right arrow SVG takes 81px of width while the arrow on its own is 56px wide. In case you need to add space around arrows - you better do it with CSS. I've added a second example with 56px wide arrows

```css
/* Add dark background to see white arrows */
.arrows-block {
  background-color: black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.swiper-button-prev-custom > svg {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="arrows-block">

    <!-- Arrow left -->
    <div class="swiper-button-prev-custom">
        <svg width="81" height="8" viewBox="0 0 81 8" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M55.3536 4.35355C55.5488 4.15829 55.5488 3.84171 55.3536 3.64645L52.1716 0.464466C51.9763 0.269204 51.6597 0.269204 51.4645 0.464466C51.2692 0.659728 51.2692 0.976311 51.4645 1.17157L54.2929 4L51.4645 6.82843C51.2692 7.02369 51.2692 7.34027 51.4645 7.53553C51.6597 7.7308 51.9763 7.7308 52.1716 7.53553L55.3536 4.35355ZM0 4.5H55V3.5H0V4.5Z" fill="white" />
        </svg>
    </div>

    <!-- Arrow right -->
    <div class="swiper-button-next-custom">
        <svg width="81" height="8" viewBox="0 0 81 8" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M55.3536 4.35355C55.5488 4.15829 55.5488 3.84171 55.3536 3.64645L52.1716 0.464466C51.9763 0.269204 51.6597 0.269204 51.4645 0.464466C51.2692 0.659728 51.2692 0.976311 51.4645 1.17157L54.2929 4L51.4645 6.82843C51.2692 7.02369 51.2692 7.34027 51.4645 7.53553C51.6597 7.7308 51.9763 7.7308 52.1716 7.53553L55.3536 4.35355ZM0 4.5H55V3.5H0V4.5Z" fill="white" />
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="arrows-block">

    <!-- Arrow left -->
    <div class="swiper-button-prev-custom">
        <svg width="56" height="8" viewBox="0 0 56 8" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M55.3536 4.35355C55.5488 4.15829 55.5488 3.84171 55.3536 3.64645L52.1716 0.464466C51.9763 0.269204 51.6597 0.269204 51.4645 0.464466C51.2692 0.659728 51.2692 0.976311 51.4645 1.17157L54.2929 4L51.4645 6.82843C51.2692 7.02369 51.2692 7.34027 51.4645 7.53553C51.6597 7.7308 51.9763 7.7308 52.1716 7.53553L55.3536 4.35355ZM0 4.5H55V3.5H0V4.5Z" fill="white" />
        </svg>
    </div>

    <!-- Arrow right -->
    <div class="swiper-button-next-custom">
        <svg width="56" height="8" viewBox="0 0 56 8" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M55.3536 4.35355C55.5488 4.15829 55.5488 3.84171 55.3536 3.64645L52.1716 0.464466C51.9763 0.269204 51.6597 0.269204 51.4645 0.464466C51.2692 0.659728 51.2692 0.976311 51.4645 1.17157L54.2929 4L51.4645 6.82843C51.2692 7.02369 51.2692 7.34027 51.4645 7.53553C51.6597 7.7308 51.9763 7.7308 52.1716 7.53553L55.3536 4.35355ZM0 4.5H55V3.5H0V4.5Z" fill="white" />
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```